# Why would a timeout avoid a tornado hang?

Tags: python, tornado

Waiting on a `concurrent.futures.Future` from a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in a Tornado coroutine sometimes hangs for me:

```
def slowinc(x):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return x + 1
yield tp_executor.submit(slowinc, 1)  # sometimes hangs
```

When I add a timeout it might hang for the timeout period, but seems to actually return the correct result after that time.

```
yield gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=5), 
                       executor.submit(...))  # hangs for 5sec, then works
```

This only happens in the context of a larger test suite, in which many unpleasant things occur (child processes are terminated mid-stride).  This error is almost certainly related to this unpleasant context and not strictly the fault of Tornado.  However, I believe that I have isolated these unpleasant things as well as possible.

So I apologize for the subtle bug and lack of a simple repeatable example.  My hope is that the odd behavior of a failing timeout actually causing success is helpful in isolating my issue.

#### Temporary Solution

So far my solution is the following:

```
while not future.done():
    try:
        yield gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=1), future)
    except gen.TimeoutError:
        pass

result = future.result()
```

This solves my immediate problem and, other than the occasional one second delay, is perfectly serviceable.  I'm still confused by the behavior though and am curious what odd things I'm doing to trigger this.

#### Update

The timeout solution above works for Python 3.4 under both Tornado 4.2 and 4.3 but neither the `timeout` solution nor the `PeriodicCallback` solution presented below in @ben-darnell 's answer resolves this problem under Python 2.7 Tornado 4.2 or 4.3.

Comment: Is the executor a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: Edited to state that this is from a ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Same problem here in python 2.7. The @gen.coroutine throws after sometime WebSocketClosedError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution but I think I can offer a simpler workaround: start up a background `PeriodicCallback` that does nothing in a short interval: `PeriodicCallback(lambda: None, 500).start()`. This will make sure the IOLoop wakes up periodically without intruding into all your `yield executor.submit()` calls.

The symptom suggests that the problem lies in the "waker" behavior of `add_callback`: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/d9c5bc8fb6530a03ebbb6da667e26685b8eee0ea/tornado/ioloop.py#L929-L944

This code was changed in Tornado 4.3 (https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/1511/files). If you're on 4.3, see if the problem still exists in 4.2. Could anything in your "unpleasant" environment be causing `thread.get_ident()` to behave differently than tornado expects?

There are reports of (rare) problems with the waker "pipe" on windows: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/1364

Comment: For what it's worth, this problem existed on Tornado 4.2.1 on linux

Comment: Both this solution and the timeout solution presented in the question fail for Python 2.7 (I was on 3.4 before) on both Tornado 4.2.1 and 4.3.0.  Any other thoughts on what this could be @ben-darnell ?  Debugging and isolating this is proving to be a challenge.