# concurrent.futures.Future from a ThreadPoolExecutor hang sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

i face a problem that the concurrent.futures.Future from a ThreadPoolExecutor hung sometimes,i use python 3.7 here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import time
import sys
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import os
from decimal import localcontext, Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
from datetime import datetime,timezone ,timedelta
import urllib3
import base64

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

class Test:
    out = []
    CONNECTIONS = 200

    f1 = open('D:/NewProxeyUserPass.txt', 'r')
    Proxies= f1.readlines()
    f1.close()

    f2 = open('D:/UserAgents.txt', 'r')
    UserAgents= f2.readlines()
    f2.close()

    MAX_RETRIES = 3

    ExcptionCount= int
    ExcptionCount=0

    BASE_URI = 'https://h.com/session.php'

    def load_url(n):
        Proxy_Port_User_Pass=Test.Proxies[n].split(":")
        useragent=Test.UserAgents[n]
        Proxy_Port_User_Pass[0].strip()
        ProxyIP =Proxy_Port_User_Pass[0].strip()
        ProxyPort =Proxy_Port_User_Pass[1].strip()
        username = Proxy_Port_User_Pass[2].strip()
        password =Proxy_Port_User_Pass[3].strip()
        usrPass = username+":"+password
        b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass.encode()).decode()
        Timestamp =int((datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
        headers = {
            "user-agent": useragent.strip(),
            "Connection":"close"
            }

        proxies = {
           "http"  :"http://" + username + ":" + password + "@"  +  ProxyIP + ":" + ProxyPort,
           "https" :"https://" + username + ":" + password + "@"  +  ProxyIP + ":" +ProxyPort
           }
        JsonSession = "{'device':'id'}"
        retries = Retry(total=3,
                       backoff_factor=0.1)
        adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries)
        with requests.Session() as session:
           session.mount('https://', adapter)
           session.keep_alive = False
           session.trust_env=False
           ans = session.post(Test.BASE_URI,
                              data=JsonSession,
                              headers=headers,
                              params={"timestamp":Timestamp},
                              proxies=proxies,
                              verify=False)
           return ans.content

    def DoWork():
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=Test.CONNECTIONS) as executor:
            future_to_url = (executor.submit(Test.load_url, n) for n in range(0,150))
            count=int
            count=1
            ExcptionCount = int
            ExcptionCount = 0
            time1 = time.time()
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                try:
                    print( str(count)+" - "+str(future.result())+"\n")
                    count = count +1
                except Exception as exc:
                        ExcptionCount=ExcptionCount+1
                        print("Exception count : "+ str(ExcptionCount) + " - "+str(exc))

        time2 = time.time()
        print(f'Took {time2-time1:.2f} s'+"\n Total Exceptions Count : "+ str(ExcptionCount))

    pass

Test.DoWork()
```

i found these 
[Why would a timeout avoid a tornado hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634956/why-would-a-timeout-avoid-a-tornado-hang/33643631#33643631)
and
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1595
but i dot not how to use it in my code,
so how to prevent concurrent.futures.Future from a ThreadPoolExecutor from hung,if you can give me working code, Thanks for help

Comment: if i run for loop with little number for example 150 will not hung but if i run it in large number like 15000 (and i need to run it in large number) will hung, any suggestion?

Comment: so if there any way to set a timeout for each worker in ThreadPoolExecutor to prevent this hung?any help?